# How do I enqueue multiple Wordpress AJAX scripts in my functions.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am currently trying to enqueue 2 Wordpress AJAX scripts in my functions.php file, but I seem to have hit an error. The first AJAX script works fine, but for the second I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

What I have so far in my AJAX scripts is this:

This first block is for my first AJAX script located in `my-ajax-script.js`.

```
function lesson_watched_call(lesson_id_value) {  
    console.log('Lesson watched fn called.');
    console.log(lesson_id_value);
    $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {
        _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,  // nonce
        action: "lesson_watched", // action call
        lesson_value: lesson_id_value // data
    });
}
```

This second block is for my second AJAX script located in `fav-ajax-script.js`.

```
function toggleFavTut(tutorial_id_value) {  
    console.log('Tutorial toggle fn called.');
    console.log(tutorial_id_value);
    $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {
        _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,  // nonce
        action: "tutorial_fav_toggle", // action call
        tutorial_value: tutorial_id_value // data
    });
}
```

In my `functions.php` file, this is what I have:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Enqeue AJAX Script and Define Lesson Watched Function  */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_scripts' );
function enqueue_ajax_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_obj',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'lesson_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fav-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script2', 'my_ajax_obj',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'tutorial_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );
}

function lesson_watched() {
    $lastValue_php = wp_unslash( $_POST['lesson_value'] );
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $found = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'lessons_watched_ids', true );

    if ( !in_array( $lastValue_php, $found ) ) :
      if( empty( $found ) ) :  
        update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'lessons_watched_ids', array( $lastValue_php ) );
      else :
        $found[] = $lastValue_php;
        update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'lessons_watched_ids', $found );
      endif;
    endif;

    wp_die(); // Ends all AJAX handlers
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_lesson_watched', 'lesson_watched');
add_action('wp_ajax_lesson_watched', 'lesson_watched');

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Enqeue AJAX Script and Define Tutorial Toggle Function  */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function tutorial_fav_toggle() {
  $tutorial_value = wp_unslash( $_POST['tutorial_value'] );
  $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

  $found = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'tutorial_favorited_ids', true );

  if ( !in_array( $tutorial_value, $found ) ) :
    $found[] = $tutorial_value;
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'tutorial_favorited_ids', $found );
  else:
    $key = array_search( $tutorial_value, $found );
    unset( $found[$key] );
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'tutorial_favorited_ids', $found );
  endif;

  wp_die(); // Ends all AJAX handlers
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tutorial_fav_toggle', 'tutorial_fav_toggle');
add_action('wp_ajax_tutorial_fav_toggle', 'tutorial_fav_toggle');
```

I first start out by enqueueing both scripts and then localizing each script. I'm wondering if maybe I have to use a different variable for some of the localize variables, but I am not certain about that. Would you have an tips on what to try to debug?

Comment: I don't remember how exactly `wp_localize_script` works, but if this simply creates new script elements, then the variables inside those will be in the global scope. So in that case, you'd have `var my_ajax_obj = ...` in your page code two times, with the latter overwriting the former. So try and use a different name for the second one - as the second parameter for `wp_localize_script`, _and_ then of course also in your second JS file.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), the second parameter to `wp_localize_script` should be unique.

> $object_name is the name of the variable which will contain the data. Note that this should be unique to both the script and to the plugin or theme. Thus, the value here should be properly prefixed with the slug or another unique value, to prevent conflicts.

So, following your pattern the second function could use `my_ajax_obj2` for the variable.

```php
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_obj',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'lesson_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fav-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script2', 'my_ajax_obj2',
          array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                 'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'tutorial_nonce_value' ),
          ) 
        );
```

Do take care to make your variable specific to your application, too. These variables all effectively are just properties on the global `window` object and everything can read/write them, so make sure they are unique.

Comment: Hi, I updated the my_ajax_objs so the second has a 2 behind it. I also updated the two references to my_ajax_obj2 in the fav_ajax_script, but I am still getting the POST error. Do you have any recommendations as to what to try next?

Comment: Do you have PHP, WordPress and MySQL error reporting all enabled so that you can see the specific error?

Comment: In the console it says: POST http://ians-guides.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error). If I go to the Network tab in the page's devtools, under the 'Name' column, 'admin-ajax.php' is listed in red, and under the 'Status' column, 500 is listed. It's odd because my first ajax script works like a charm, but the second is erroring for some reason.